# How to update particular td state in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My table has Dynamic data that generate 'td'. So I have to update the state of the particular selected td in react. each 'td' have the dynamic Id's if it is useful.. please give me the suggestion to update the selected 'td' state

Comment: Can you show us some of your code ?

Comment: Please read about this.setState method

Comment: When i am setState the td value that will updates the all td's in table rows
I need to update particular td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store all td's in array and pass perticular object to setState and then map all td's in render

Answer (score 0):

Just make td as Separate Component which has own state and update data there. In this way You will make each td independent and "autonomic".